# Is it possible to get the wallclock time associated with a WMI query?

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to derive either local or UTC time associated with the results of a WMI query run against a remote system

The following is my WMI query:

```
SELECT PercentProcessorTime, Timestamp_Sys100NS FROM Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor
```

I am then able to get the time:

```
var timeStampTime = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc({timestamp_sys100ns})
```

However, FromFileTimeUtc takes a **long** and when I run this WMI query against some machines, the resulting timestamp_sys100NS (which is a **ulong**) is invalid for this conversion.

e.g. I just ran it against one system and it returned **18446741803737700000**, which I have no idea how to parse.

Please note this is the time *on the remote machine* and it should be the time associated with the query (it is too inaccurate for me to subsequently query **Win32_UTCTime**, for example)

Thanks :)

Comment: Turns out it's a windows 2003 problem! 2008+ seems to report a TimeStamp which can be converted to a DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem seems only related to when I query Windows Server 2003.
In this case the timestamp appears to be the time since the system was booted.

When I query Windows Server 2008, 2008R2, 2012 etc, the Timestamp returned is convertible to a wallclock time directly.